# How to connect Android emulator with local mysql database

Tags: java, android, emulation

I want to connect mysql database locally with android emulator. I used http GET and POST methods for accessing data from Google Cloud SQL with app engine but i want to connect it with locally using phpmyadmin..

when i use following code it show Toast for connection failed

```
        String result = "";
        //the year data to send
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name","Hammad"));

        //http post
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/myApp/read_data.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

                Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                is.close();

                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
               Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        //parse json data
        try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("user_id")+
                                ", Username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
                                ", Name: "+json_data.getInt("name")+
                                ", City: "+json_data.getInt("city")
                        );
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("pingspot");
     
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user name = '".$_REQUEST['name']."'");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
            $output[]=$e;
     
    print(json_encode($output));
    
 
    mysql_close();
?>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running this within the emulator `localhost:3306` won't work.  Replace that with the IP address of the machine running MySQL.  So for example if your local dev machine (running MySQL) uses IP 192.168.0.10, change that to `192.168.0.10:3306`.

Just to expand a bit - when you attempt to access http://localhost:3306 within the emulator (or even on a device) it tries to connect to the port 3306 on the loopback address (on the emulator/device).  You obviously don't have the SQL service running on the android so this doesn't make sense.

Also, depending on your OS configuration, you may have to open port 3306 in your firewall.

Edit: Warren's tip (below) leads me to the [details](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking) in the Android docs.  May want to stick with 10.0.2.2 if you don't want to mess around with your OS' firewall.

Comment: Just some more information: If you want to get the `localhost` from the machine that runs the emulator, you need to use `10.0.2.2` - short details: http://www.droidnova.com/ever-tried-localhost-with-the-android-emulator,102.html

Comment: Thanks Marvin and Warren for quick reply, you are right, i use above method to loopback on local machine, its working fine.. another problem that i faced is that when i submit my first query in first activity it works fine at same time i move to the 2nd activity but in second activity it doesn't work for my second query. I checked it by replacing second activity as launcher activity(instead of first activity) and it starts working.. What i am doing wrong?